# SQL Server Exception Message Format

Tags: sql-server-2012

On this page [Sql Server Errors 1-999](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645611(v=sql.105).aspx) there is a list of SQL Server errors and the associated message text.

For example:

> Err 2627: Violation of %ls constraint '%.*ls'. Cannot insert duplicate
>   key in object '%.*ls'.

An example of this exception is:

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint
>   'AK_AdvanceShipmentNotices_CustomerId_PurchaseOrderNumber'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AdvanceShipmentNotices'. The
>   duplicate key value is (4, 1000).

The example error text contains placeholders: %ls and %.*ls. Looking through the rest of the error examples, there are a number of other placeholders, e.g. %d, %s, %S_DATE, %hs, %S_TS, %x, and so on.

**QUESTION**: are these placeholders defined anywhere, or do I simply need to work out for myself what they all mean?

Other example errors:

- Err  21: Warning: Fatal error %d occurred at %S_DATE. Note the error and time, and contact your system administrator.
- Err 103: The %S_MSG    that starts with '%.*ls' is too long. Maximum length is %d.
- Err 262: %ls permission denied in database '%.*ls'.
- Err 407: Internal error. The string routine in file %hs, line %d failed    with HRESULT 0x%x.
- Err 408: A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position %i.
- Err 479: Invalid ROWS value or REPEATABLE seed "%I64d" in the TABLESAMPLE clause for table "%.*ls". The value or seed must be greater than 0.
- Err 532: The timestamp (changed to %S_TS) shows that the row has been updated by another user.
- Err 552: CryptoAPI function '%ls' failed. Error 0x%x: %ls
- Err 2627: Violation of %ls constraint '%.*ls'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object '%.*ls'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the T-SQL `RAISERROR` function provides more information:

> msg_str is a string of characters with optional embedded conversion specifications. Each conversion specification defines how a value in the argument list is formatted and placed into a field at the location of the conversion specification in msg_str. Conversion specifications have this format:
>
> % [[flag] [width] [. precision] [{h | l}]] type

*flag*

> Is a code that determines the spacing and justification of the substituted value.

Codes:

- `-`: Left-justify the argument value within the given field width.
- `+`: Preface the argument value with a plus (+) or minus (-) if the value is of a signed type.
- `0`: Preface the output with zeros until the minimum width is reached. When 0 and the minus sign (-) appear, 0 is ignored.
- `#`: When used with the o, x, or X format, the number sign (#) flag prefaces any nonzero value with 0, 0x, or 0X, respectively. When d, i, or u are prefaced by the number sign (#) flag, the flag is ignored.
- (blank): Preface the output value with blank spaces if the value is signed and positive. This is ignored when included with the plus sign (+) flag.

*width*

> Is an integer that defines the minimum width for the field into which the argument value is placed. If the length of the argument value is equal to or longer than width, the value is printed with no padding. If the value is shorter than width, the value is padded to the length specified in width.
>   An asterisk (*) means that the width is specified by the associated argument in the argument list, which must be an integer value.

*precision*

> Is the maximum number of characters taken from the argument value for string values. For example, if a string has five characters and precision is 3, only the first three characters of the string value are used.
>   For integer values, precision is the minimum number of digits printed.
>   An asterisk (*) means that the precision is specified by the associated argument in the argument list, which must be an integer value.

*{h | l} type*

> Is used with character types d, i, o, s, x, X, or u, and creates shortint (h) or longint (l) values.

Type specifications

- `d` or `i`: Signed integer
- `o`: Unsigned octal
- `s`: String
- `u`: Unsigned integer
- `x` or `X`: Unsigned hexadecimal

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Comment: Thankyou. That's exactly what I was looking for. (I'm still a bit confused as to what '%.*ls' means. According to the documentation, '*' "means that the precision is specified by the associated argument in the argument list, which must be an integer value". Which in the example above, it isn't. Also, 'l' means 'longint' - how does that apply to 's', a string?). Anyway, I think I've got what I need. Thanks again!